# Beamer customizing \citeauthor

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am using Beamer for preparing presentation in Turkish. Frequently, I need the command `\citeauthor`. I have replaced "*and*" between the authors into Turkish ("*ve*") and "*et al.*" too. However, I want to remove (or replace) the comma just before "*and*" when there are three or more authors but I **don't** know how to do it.

Below, you will see my output.

[image]

What I need is the following. `Ladas, Qian, Vlahos ve Yan`.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,firstinits=true,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=4]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  and = {ve},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article {MR1103855,
    AUTHOR = {Ladas, G. and Qian, C. and Vlahos, P. N. and Yan, J.},
     TITLE = {Stability of solutions of linear nonautonomous difference equations},
   JOURNAL = {Appl. Anal.},
  FJOURNAL = {Applicable Analysis. An International Journal},
    VOLUME = {41},
      YEAR = {1991},
    NUMBER = {1-4},
     PAGES = {183--191},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item What I get: \citeauthor{MR1103855}.
\item What I need: Ladas, Qian, Vlahos ve Yan.
\end{itemize}
\alert{Note that \texttt{{\textbackslash}citeauthor} command gives a comma before {\textquotedblleft}ve{\textquotedblright}.}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}



\usepackage[backend=bibtex,giveninits=true,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=4]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  and = {ve},
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article {MR1103855,
    AUTHOR = {Ladas, G. and Qian, C. and Vlahos, P. N. and Yan, J.},
     TITLE = {Stability of solutions of linear nonautonomous difference equations},
   JOURNAL = {Appl. Anal.},
  FJOURNAL = {Applicable Analysis. An International Journal},
    VOLUME = {41},
      YEAR = {1991},
    NUMBER = {1-4},
     PAGES = {183--191},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item What I get: \citeauthor{MR1103855}.
\item What I need: Ladas, Qian, Vlahos ve Yan.
\end{itemize}
\alert{Note that \texttt{{\textbackslash}citeauthor} command gives a comma before {\textquotedblleft}ve{\textquotedblright}.}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And please note that 'firstinits' option is deprecated, use 'giveninits' instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you mind telling me which file should I check to modify it?

Comment: Just put `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}` into the preamble of your presentation? Or what exactly is the question?

Comment: Which file did you check to decide that we should change the variable '\finalandcomma'?

Comment: @bkarpuz Ah, now I understand. Right now I looked it up in one of my own projects, where I used it. Back than I probably just googled it and most likely found some question on this website.